# Florence: ZTL clarification

Tags: italy, florence, restricted-areas

We are planning a trip for someone in our family. Part of the trip would include parking in Florence near Santa Maria Novella train station. There is a private garage right across the station, [Garage La Stazione](https://www.garagelastazione.it/). The garage seems to be  inside zone B of the ZTL.

The driving instructions in the garage's web site include this sentence:

> NOTE: at the beginning of Via Jacopo Da Diacceto there is a sign indicating a ban on driving older cars (Euro 1 and Euro 2); this does not stop you from reaching the garage.

[The sign](https://www.google.com/maps/@43.7788024,11.2426969,3a,75y,179.05h,77.19t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s_qqM-_Sl5evth2R71Sn9gA!2e0!7i16384!8i8192) does not seem to mention the ZTL, though all the maps I find show that the ZTL zone starts there. In trying to clarify how the access to the ZTL zone works, and since I found references online that hotels and parkings can whitelist license plates, I sent an email to the garage. Their reply was

> As far as the ZTL is concerned, we are outside so access to our parking is free.
> Remember to access our car park via Via Jacopo da Diacceto.

In searching, I found [this comment](https://www.tripadvisor.it/ShowTopic-g187895-i68-k13362074-Parcheggio_Stazione_Santa_Maria_Novella_evitando_ZTL-Florence_Tuscany.html) on TripAdvisor (translated):

> The entry route is: viale f.lli Rosselli - via Jacopo da Diacceto, at the end of which are the entrances to a private garage and the public underground car park; don't be impressed by the ZTL indications, those who stop at the car parks can ignore them.

So, what's going on exactly? Is Via Luigi Alamanni by the train station **not** in the ZTL? Is there some kind of exception over these streets that allows one to ignore the ZTL? Does the car's license plate need to be whitelisted by the parking garage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The municipal services published the [map](https://servizi.comune.fi.it/sites/www.comune.fi.it/files/all_a_-_perimetrazione_ztl_e_varchi_2022.pdf) of the ZTL zone, and *via Jacopo da Diacceto* is firmly in *Settore B* (Sector B) of the ZTL

> Is there some kind of exception over these streets that allows one to ignore the ZTL?

**Yes,** the [ZTL Act](https://servizi.comune.fi.it/sites/www.comune.fi.it/files/2011-m-04192_aggiornata_al_2020-04-04.pdf) states:

> Lungo tutti gli itinerari sopra indicati è consentito il transito per accedere alle autorimesse che si trovino sugli stessi. Non sono pertanto rilasciate autorizzazioni di transito del tipo “Autorimessa” a coloro che hanno a disposizione autorimesse o aree private per il ricovero di veicoli lungo i suddetti itinerari

*DeepL's translation :*

> Along all the above routes, transit is allowed to access garages located on them. Therefore, transit permits of the type "Garage" shall not be issued to those who have garages or private areas available for the parking of vehicles along the above routes

And *via Jacopo da Diacceto* is part of a transit itinerary :

> ##### 4 - Itinerari di transito consentito ai non autorizzati
>
> È consentito il transito senza necessità di autorizzazione lungo i seguenti itinerari interni alla ZTL:
>
> [...]
>
> d) via J. Da Diacceto, via Alamanni, via Santa Caterina da Siena, via della Scala (nel tratto fra via
> S. Caterina da Siena e viale F.lli Rosselli)

*DeepL's translation :*

> ##### 4 - Transit routes allowed for the unauthorized.
>
> Transit is allowed without the need for a permit along the following routes within the LTZ:
>
> [...]
>
> d) via J. Da Diacceto, via Alamanni, via Santa Caterina da Siena, via della Scala (In the section between St. Catherine of Siena Street and F.lli Rosselli Avenue.)